# Selenium Webdriver: visibilityOfElementLocated although element not visible

Tags: html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm facing the problem that the Firefox Webdriver does not determine correctly if an element is visible or not: This is the code I'm using, which returns that the element is visible although it's not

```
wait.ignoring(UnhandledAlertException.class).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ad")));
```

Now, what if I am testing a website, where the element can be found in the source of the site but is not visible (e.g. because there is another element in front of it). From what I could gather the `visibilityOfElementLocated` method only checks if the element's width and height is >0, doesn't it?
Is there a way to check if the element is REALLY visible for a user surfing on the site, considering bad layout and wrong z-indexes etc.? This would really be great...

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you are not trying to actually test for presenceOfElementLocated instead of visibilityOfElementLocated ?  The visibilityOfElementLocated only works if the locator you search for has the display CSS attribute set.  Some people test "elementExists" by using ".findElements(By).size() > 0" but here is an alternative method that requires handling exceptions.

This might be overkill, but you could write your own visibility function. In this example I call it "elementExists()".  It tests for "presenceOf" but then handles the "visiblity" exception if there is one:

```
public boolean elementExists( By locator ) {   
    WebElement foo = null;
    try {
        foo = this.getElementByLocator( locator, 10 );
     } catch ( TimeoutException te) {
        System.out.println("There was a timeout looking for element: " + 
            locator.toString() );
        //Swallow exception: ExceptionUtils.getMessage(te);
        return false;
    } catch ( ElementNotVisibleException env ) {
        System.out.println("The element was found but is invisible: " +
            locator.toString() );
        //Swallow exception: ExceptionUtils.getMessage(env);
        return false;
    }
    if ( foo == null ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public WebElement getElementByLocator( By locator, int timeout ) {
    System.out.println("Calling method getElementByLocator: " + 
        locator.toString() );
    int interval = 5;
    if ( timeout <= 20 ) interval = 3;
    if ( timeout <= 10 ) interval = 2;
    if ( timeout <= 4 ) interval = 1;
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>( se.myDriver )
        .withTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .pollingEvery(interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .ignoring( NoSuchElementException.class, 
                       StaleElementReferenceException.class );
    WebElement we = wait.until( ExpectedConditions
           .presenceOfElementLocated( locator ) );
    return we;
}
```